# Cognnos Query - Issues while generating the sql

Tags: sql, report, cognos

Here is an issue I am facing while generating the sql of a query.

There is one query named "Product_Base". Some basic quantities are being calculated here. Another Query named "Product_Display" is refering the previous "Product_Base" Query and deriving some more quantities. But whenever I am trying to generate the sql for "Product_Display" , I am getting only the sql of "Product_Base". Can you please give possible solutions from your end ? Responses are highly appreciated !!

Comment: Can you post your code and actual results?

Comment: There is no code. Its an issue of Cognos BI.

Comment: How are you generating the SQL?  What query (or queries) are actually used in the report?

Comment: Please post the SQL you are getting. That's what mjuarez meant by "code". That should help make things clearer.